# R GroupBy function using google analytics data

Tags: r

I have extracted data from the Google Analytics API through R.
The metrics are date, landing page and users

EXTRACTING DATA THROUGH R

```
g<- p %>% group_by(landingPagePath="/pricing/")
View(g)
```

OUTPUT

```
 date       |landing page  |users
---------------------------------
2019-01-14 | /pricing/    |3
2019-01-14 | /pricing/    |1
2019-01-14 | /pricing/    |1
2019-01-15 | /pricing/    |4
2019-01-15 | /pricing/    |1
2019-01-16 | /pricing/    |10
```

I need output as:

```
date       |users
---------------------------------
2019-01-14 |  5
2019-01-15 |  5
2019-01-16 |  10
```

I have tried already the code but the output is coming as No data Available

```
 gv <- g %>%group_by(date='2018-01-14')  %>% filter(users==sum(users))
```

Comment: Possibily `g %>% group_by(date) %>% summarise(users=sum(users))` ?

Comment: Nithya, the question is what you intend to do with `group_by(date='2018-01-14')`. You might mean to group everything that is on that date versus everything that is not, in which case you need an equality test, `group_by(date=='2018-01-14')`. If, however, you mean to group that date together and not include other dates at all, in which case you need `filter(date=='2018-01-14')`. Otherwise, as-is you are *assigning a static value* to all of `date` and not really grouping it (which is almost certainly not what you need).

Comment: @RLave Thank You... It worked

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using 
Data

```
df <-read.table(text="date          landing_page    users
14-01-2019  pricing 3
14-01-2019  pricing 1
14-01-2019  pricing 1
15-01-2019  pricing 4
15-01-2019  pricing 1
16-01-2019  pricing 10
",header = T)
```

str(df)

Result

```
library(lubridate)
df$date <-dmy(df$date)

df1 <- aggregate(users ~ date,df , sum)
```